# deploy .NET on Apache

Tags: .net, setup-deployment

We are switching our web development from Java to .NET

We currently have an Apache/Tomcat server to host our war files.

I understand that .NET needs to run on IIS or on Apache with mod_mono.

My boss is concerned with the IIS setup since we currently use IIS for ONE process off our iSeries and quite regularly that server needs to be restarted.

Our Apache server is quite solid and rarely requires restarting.  However, a developer on staff doesn't think that the mod_mono (or any other Apache plug-in) would be stable.

Does anyone have any references they can share on the stability of the 2 platforms?  Is there another solution that I'm unaware of?  What set up does your organization use for hosting .NET applications

Answer (score 1):

We run a number of applications (roughly 100) on IIS on a set of servers, which are used by roughly 500 people on and off all day, every week day.

These run on Windows Server 2008 (64 bit) machines, and we restart the aspnet processes probably once a week (or less).

This is to deploy new code, not because of any other reason.

Personally, I wouldn't run a .net project on anything except IIS.

Comment: that's good to hear! I'll pass that up to my boss, maybe he'll have a better outlook on IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Many IIS servers are running for long time without any problems, the problems you're having are likely to be either related to some 3rd-party software or a hardware/driver problem.

That said, I have heard that mod_mono is working pretty well, but I doubt that it does really outperform IIS in any category (security, stability or performance-wise).

Note also that Apache Tomcat is something completely different than Apache HTTPD, which is the platform for mod_mono.

Comment: thanks for the information on the mod_mono platform requirement...I'm new to web server management and need all the guidance I can get!